# How do you work with low-res footage and render with high-res footage in the video editor?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

It is choppy using 1080p footage on my computer. I would like to downscale everything beforehand to even 320 x 180, do filters and picture in picture and have it applied later to the big files for rendering.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internal proxy generation is very slow in Blender, but what you do is to add all of your clips to the timeline and select them all(A).

Go to the sidebar, hit Set Selected Strip Proxies.

Choose your Proxy resolution.

Hit Rebuild Proxy.

Wait.

In Preview open the sidebar, in the View Tab, select the Proxy resolution.
(the proxies will stay even though you remove all of your footage again)

Or use this add-on for faster batch rendering of proxies: 
[blendervelvets.org/en/velvet-revolver](https://blendervelvets.org/en/velvet-revolver)

Comment: After importing in Blender 2.8, where do I find it? Velvet or revolver does not show up.

Comment: You need to scroll down the Velvet Revolver Page for instructions: http://blendervelvets.org/en/velvet-revolver/

This is where you find VR in the menus:
https://i1.wp.com/blendervelvets.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/velvet_revolver01.jpg